# Not able to get proper parent category for specific child category

Tags: magento2

I have "ABC" as a parent category and "XYZ" as a child category. While opening the "XYZ" child category, on that page breadcrumb is appeared as below

`Home > XYZ (child category) > ABC (parent category)`

instead of

`Home > ABC (parent category) > XYZ (child category)`

I have used below code to get category breadcrumbs:

```
if ($category->getParentCategories()) 
{
    foreach ($category->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
        $breadcrumbs[] = [
            'label' => $parent->getName()
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your in Magento Admin? If not got to admin->catalog->categories and rearrange categories as per needed

Comment: Yes, Initially I had do this steps in admin, but could not got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the categories IDs stored in the current categorie's path in store and process it in reverse order like this:

```php
$pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
$pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));
$categories = $category->getParentCategories();

// add category path breadcrumb
foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
    if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && $categories[$categoryId]->getName()) {
       $breadcrumbs[] = $categories[$categoryId]->getName();
   }
}
```

Comment: While checking the category attribute "path_in_store" entry in database and found that their is no any entries for all the categories in database.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace Your-Vendor\Your-Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Category extends Template{

    protected $categoryFactory;
    protected $registry;
    protected $category;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getCategory($categoryId)
    {
        $this->category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        $this->category->load($categoryId);
        return $this->category;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$product = $this->getCurrentProduct();

$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId){
    $category = $this->getCategory($categoryId);
    $parentCategories = $category->getparent_id();
    echo $parentCategories. '<br />';
}
?>
```